# WorkManger works on Oreo but not Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

`WorkManager` states that it works on OSes before `JobScheduler` and the like, yet it doesn't seem to work on API levels that use `AlarmManager`. I have a `PeriodicWorkRequest` which runs in intervals just fine on Oreo, but on Lollipop, it only runs the first time.

The code in question (`PeriodicWorker.class` is my own `class` of course):

```
WorkManager
                    .getInstance()
                    .enqueue(
                            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                                    PeriodicWorker.class,
                                    PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS,
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                            )
                                    .setConstraints(
                                            new Constraints.Builder()
                                                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                                                    .build()
                                    )
                                    .build()
                    );
```

My WorkManager dependency is `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha03`.

Here's a demo project: https://gitlab.com/neelkamath/work-manager-demo

Comment: Can you create a simple project or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lollipop's functionality has been fixed in the newer version: `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha04`.