# WorkManager - PeriodicWorkRequest not working on android api 21

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to schedule a periodic check with PeriodicWorkRequest. It works great on android API 23 and above, but not on android API 21. On API 21 it works only once.

Here is a sample code
`PeriodicWorkRequest worker = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker.class, MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).setConstraints(Constraints.NONE).addTag(TAG_PERIODIC_WORK_REQUEST).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(worker);`

Tested with the latest **alpha03** and also **alpha02**
What I'm doing wrong? Or could it be a bug?

Comment: Can you use latest version alpha03?

Comment: Tested, same result, not working on 21

Comment: I have the same exact problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861872/workmanger-works-on-oreo-but-not-lollipop). I'm making a demo project and will show tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed in alpha04 version

Comment: i have alpha05 version, still facing the issue

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I just verified that this is a bug on our end. We should have a fix in `alpha04`. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Will wait to test the new alpha04.

Comment: hey rahul. I use workmanager for periodic work. But when I kill the app, my worker stops & doesn't work periodically. What should I do?